# Android: requestPermissions flow

Tags: android, android-permissions

My code looks something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DateSelectorActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        long theDate = 0;
        theDate = data.getLongExtra("theDate", theDate);
        if (theDate != 0) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please?!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR}, 1);
                return;
            }
            doTheCalendarReading();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0  && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                doTheCalendarReading();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Oh well...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}


private void doTheCalendarReading() {
    String[] projection = new String[]{CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION};

    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.setTimeInMillis(theDate);
    startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.setTimeInMillis(theDate);
    endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    endTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    endTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

    String selection = "(( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " >= " + startTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ) AND ( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " <= " + endTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ))";

    Cursor cursor = this.getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Toast.makeText( this.getApplicationContext(), "Title: " + cursor.getString(1) + " Start-Time: " + (new Date(cursor.getLong(3))).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        } while ( cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

The flow in general is: When pressing a button, I open an activity to receive a date (that's working fine). Once I get the date, I want to retrieve the calendar events on that date.

Regarding the line

```
Cursor cursor = this.getBaseContext().getContentResolver()
                   .query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
                          projection, selection, null, null);
```

I got a red zigzag telling me I should ask for the relevant permission.

So I did and if the permission already granted I call `doTheCalendarReading()` and if not, I ask for the permission and if granted, again I call `doTheCalendarReading()`.

I moved the code that requires the permission into that function but again it gives me a red zigzag telling me I need to ask for permission.

Now I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Android Marshmallow introduces an entirely new spin on application permissions,Users now have the ability to revoke runtime permissions whenever they desire. This means that you can’t assume the app has access to the permission, even if it had been granted previously. You can refer [PermissionsDispatcher lib](http://hotchemi.github.io/PermissionsDispatcher/) or this [guide](https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-permissions-model-ba1d5d6c0610#.1jpsx34a6).I Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is in design time and not when running the app. I already asked for the permission before calling the permission-required command. The only way to get rid of the red zigzag is asking for the permission just above it but it's a-sync and the result is retrieved in a callback function...

Comment: I use https://github.com/kayvannj/PermissionUtil for action take a picture from camera with flow like you. If permission is granted, I excute action take photo, else I have a alert error, It works fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the *red zigzag* you mention is a lint warning. If this is NOT the case, please clarify on that and I will update my answer.

In case we are talking about a lint warning, this first and foremost means that it is in general NOT a big deal, you can still compile as lint warnings are more like advisories than hard requirements. However, some build systems that incorporate lint checks will fail anyway, so I see why you might have an interest in solving this issue beside the fact that it is visually annoying.

Sure, the warning is there for a reason, but static program analysis is prone to overapproximation so in your case it seems that either it is a false positive or there are some cases (probably corner cases) where the check is not reached, maybe a strange sequence of callbacks.

So if you are sure that you did reasonably well with checking and requesting the permission, you could suppress the warning. Android Studio provides you with a multitude of possibilities to do this, but if you prefer doing it by hand you could just add `//noinspection MissingPermission` right above the `query` call.